# Density Function and CDF of a Uniform Random Variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose a random variable is equally likely to fall anywhere in the interval
$[a,b]$.

Then the PDF is of the form:

$$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a} & \text{if }a\leq x\leq b\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Find and sketch the corresponding CDF.
plzz help how I can find this in detail description..

Comment: Apply $F_X(x)=\int^x_{-\infty} f_X(y)dy$ discerning the cases $x<a$,$a\leq x<b$ and $b\leq x$.

Comment: You might want to try the title "Mathematics" one day...

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** Following the suggestion of @drhab: For the case $a = 2$ and $b = 4,$ here are plots of the density function $f(x)$ (at left)
and the cumulative distribution function $F(x).$

[image]